# How to disable horizontal scroll in visual studio code?

Tags: scroll, visual-studio-code

When I scroll with the touch pad with two fingers in Visual Studio Code, I often scroll to the sides a little by accident. This is a bit annoying.
I'd be happy to have it scroll *only* up and down.

Answer (score 120):

A partially satisfying solution, is to simply press `Alt + z`, to have the lines wrapped, and then it doesn't scroll to the side.
You can also make wordWrap default as described here [How do I turn on text wrapping by default in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561881/how-do-i-turn-on-text-wrapping-by-default-in-vs-code)

Comment: If you don't want to use word wrap on long lines of code, you can use `shift+mousewheel` to scroll horizontally, or `shift+alt+mousewheel` which is faster. (This doesn't help the OP on a tablet, but I find it better on the desktop than using the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Or just hit `home` twice to move to the start of the line.

Comment: On version 1.47.3 (Mac), enabling word wrap doesn't disable horizontal scrolling.  The original problem still persists.  This is due to Gitlens (see other answer).

Comment: For macOS Big Sur Version 11.5.2 `option+z` worked.

Answer (score 60):

If you have this problem because of Gitlens (blame lines), the solution i found is to disable `gitlens.currentLine.scrollable` (or set it to false in the settings json file.

Comment: Similarly with ErrorLens there is a "Scrollbar hack" setting to fix this.

Answer (score 27):

**Pressing `alt + z` (windows) or `⌥ + z` (mac) to disable/enable horizontal scrolling, works fine for a current single file.**

**If you want permanent solution for every file you visit? then follow:**

`Settings` > `Text Editor` > `Diff Editor` > `Word Wrap` to `on`

[image]

**Note:** in case you don't know where is this `Settings`, just go

**1. Via MENU**

`File` > `Preferences` > `Settings` > `Text Editor` > `Diff Editor` > `Word Wrap`

**2. Via shortcut Keys**

`On Windows`

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> (control + comma)

`On Mac`

<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> (command + comma)

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me..the horizontal scrolling is still enabled even after turning on word wrap.

Answer (score 10):

Just press **ALT + Z** -> To enable/disable the horizontal scroll

Comment: shortcut is used by nvdia geforce experience, do u know the exact setting of this, so that I can go manually toggle it

Answer (score 9):

Just want to add that some plugins, like GitLens, may mess this setting up.

E.g., with GitLens, it can add git `blame` information inline, at the end of each line of code, showing you who is responsible for that line's current version, and when.

Unfortunately, this information will not only be to the right of the `wrap` column, e.g. 80, it'll also "unlock" the horizontal scrolling, even when no GitLens blame annotation is there.

I haven't found any fix for this other than disabling such features.

Comment: Think this should be a comment and not answer (or maybe even open a new question)

Answer (score 7):

⌥ + z

the shortcut for Mac. you welcome

Answer (score 3):

Config: MBP 2018 | Using Magic Mouse 2.

For me, I had accidentally set the **'Scroll Beyond Last Column'** to **80** chars. Just resetting it to default settings is what worked for me. Hope it does for you all!

[image]

Update (6th Feb, 2021): Enabling the mini-map again causes the problem. So disabled it to get rid of the issue.

Comment: For me default, 5, was still a problem, setting to 0 was the final pain relief :)

Answer (score 2):

February 2020 (version 1.43) update adds an option called: **`Scroll Predominant Axis`**

[Scrolling predominant axis](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_43#_scrolling-predominant-axis)

> When trying to scroll vertically using a modern touchpad, it oftentimes happens that the file scrolls horizontally as well. There is now a new setting, editor.scrollPredominantAxis (which is set to true by default) which blocks "diagonal" scrolling. This forces scrolling gestures to be either vertical or horizontal (based on the highest absolute scroll delta), but never diagonal.

**When enabled,it prevents any diagonal scrolling.

It guesses your scrolling to either `vertical scroll` or `horizontal scroll`**.

It says by default it is enabled. If not then you can enable in `Scroll Predominant Axis` in settings.

Screenshot: [Editor: Scroll Predominant Axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGNQ1.png)

Or in settings.json

```json
"editor.scrollPredominantAxis": true
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed Word Wrap Column and saw scroll.

`File > Preferences > Settings > Text Editor > Diff Editor > Word Wrap Column`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Late to the question, but because the in-VS-Code solutions were not to my liking I looked elsewhere:

If you are on a Mac with with Magic Mouse you can use [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/) to disable Horizontal Scrolling just for the Code app.

Answer (score -2):

Use Ctrl + E, then Ctrl + W for disable horizontal scrolling.

For more details, you can refer this cite: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/disable-horizontal-scrolling-in-visual-studio-2019/612873.