# VS Code Scrolling - New Update

Tags: visual-studio-code, scroll

I have a problem that appeared with the new vs code update.

If I scroll vertically to a line that is long, it automatically scrolls(horizontally)  to the end of that line and I can't seem to find anything in settings to help me with that problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing alt + z to disable horizontal scrolling, works fine for a current single file. You can solve this permanently [by using word wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45672674/16313545). Either go to settings and search for "word wrap" and turn it on or go to [settings.json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43219246/16313545) and put `"editor.wordWrap": "on"`, which should be set to "on" (the default value is "off").
If you have this problem because of [Gitlens (blame lines)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56609824/16313545), the solution i found is to disable `gitlens.currentLine.scrollable` (or set it to false in the settings json file.